# Convert julian date to Gregorian before insert to database larav

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-6, jalali-calendar

Im using Morilog\Jalali package

I have datepicker input that The output like this:  1400/08/01

I want to convert this to gregorian and insert that to database

My database field is datetime
My  Controller Store method is this:

```
Panelfile::create([

'title' => $request->title,

'color' => $request->color,

'expiration' => \morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::createCarbonFromFormat('Y/m/d', $request->expiration),

]);
```

But i have this error:
**Undifine index:year**

How solve that?

Comment: @Manojkiran.A  :)

Comment: can you write your full error message?

Comment: Thats full error just 3 word

Comment: Can you give me your telegram id to send you the error photo behzad?

Comment: \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::createCarbonFromFormat('Y/m/d', $request->expiration)
  try this

Comment: I still use the same see the code I put

Comment: morilog have to like this: Morlilog first word have to be uppercase

Comment: I undrestood  that I wrote it like this here, it is written in capital letters in the controller

Comment: Where do you think the problem comes from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236324/discussion-between-behzad-and-sina).

Comment: check this link may help you
https://github.com/morilog/jalali/issues/10
$request->expiration must be complete date like 0000/00/00

Answer (score 0):

You should use [toGregorian](https://github.com/morilog/jalali#togregorianjyear-jmonth-jday) to convert Jalali to Gregorian. Like this:

```
\Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::toGregorian(1395, 2, 18); // [2016, 5, 7]
```

Notice that the output is an array: so, if you want to store the string in DB, you can `implode` the output with `-`.